# spring-boot-devtools fails on JAR with missing MANIFEST.MF

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have simple Spring Boot application using 1.4.0.M2 which works fine. When I add `spring-boot-devtools` to the mix the application refuses to start:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.ChangeableUrls.…
      getUrlsFromClassPathAttribute(ChangeableUrls.java:121)
```

The culprit is `javax.inject:javax.inject:1` which does not contain a MANIFEST.MF. Of course one might argue that it’s a faulty JAR, but unfortunately it’s quite a common one. It looks like a bug in Spring Boot to me to react this way.

How can I circumvent this behaviour short of not using `javax.inject`?

Comment: In my local Maven repository, there are also `javax.transaction:jta:1.0.1B` and `org.magicwerk:brownies-collections:0.9.9` without a manifest. Really few, out of over 7000 JARs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue has been [fixed on master](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/5704) and will be available in Spring Boot `1.4.0.M3`.